# How to manage multiple users in GCP for same level of access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

We are working with a service provider where I constantly need to add a new user in GCP IAM and assign the similar roles which I have assigned to 20 other members.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can create a group, assign some roles to this group and keep adding new users to the group so I don't have to focus on the roles etc.

Comment: Maybe your looking for this https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console

Comment: @FerreginaPelona please elaborate your comment and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this `Community Wiki` for better visibility. Proper documentation link for managing groups was already provided by @Ferregina Pelona

You can create a group for users with the same permissions in GCP. Google also recommends using this approach.

In the documentation [Best Practice - Delegate responsibility with groups and service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations#groups-and-service-accounts) you can find exemple usage of Google Groups.

> We recommend collecting users with the same responsibilities into groups and assigning IAM roles to the groups rather than to individual users. For example, you can create a "data scientist" group and assign appropriate roles to enable interaction with BigQuery and Cloud Storage. When a new data scientist joins your team, you can simply add them to the group and they will inherit the defined permissions. You can create and manage groups through the [Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/).

Regarding creation, removing and managing google groups, you should read the [Managing groups in the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console) guide.